# Convert from classic .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET 5.0

Tags: .net

I can create a new project with .NET 5.0. But when I opened the project with .NET Framework 4.5, I don't see the .NET 5.0.

[image]

Comment: Your project is **either** on the full/classic .NET framework stack (v1.0 up to v4.8) - ***OR*** it is on the **.NET Core** side of things - versions 1.0 through 5.0. Those are like **two entirely** different worlds! You cannot just "convert" your existing (full/classic) .NET 4.8 project to a **.NET Core** (v5.0) project by selecting from a dropdown ....

Comment: That's because .NET 5.0 is based on .NET Core, not .NET Framework, so migration of a .NET Framework project is more than just "changing the framework version". See the following guideline from Microsoft: [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)